# sm64-port built using mingw-w64 GCC (MSYS2) under Github Actions won't run, exit code 132

Tags: gcc, github-actions, mingw-w64, windows-container

> **Update:** I believed this happened due issues with
> [upload-artifact](https://github.com/actions/upload-artifact) action,
> namely, corrupted ZIP when downloading the artifact, as
> [many](https://github.com/actions/upload-artifact/issues/74)
> [issues](https://github.com/actions/upload-artifact/issues/156)
> addressed that (and apparently persist today).
>
> However, after building again and again, and after adding a checksum
> to the workflow, checksum differs between builds, producing the following checksums (in chronological order, newest to oldest):
>
> - ❌`025e1095d37a97776d2d03cb42772321c3bdc9c1 *build/us_pc/sm64.us.exe` [[logs](https://pipelinesghubeus8.actions.githubusercontent.com/p4R3lFxSm6lxRfpK94ViNn7tklFC2k5fO9TY2Z9EqhtckEjydu/_apis/pipelines/1/runs/14/signedlogcontent/2?urlExpires=2023-10-10T17%3A33%3A54.8905612Z&urlSigningMethod=HMACV1&urlSignature=Uvgb1f85%2FilJvrtN487dTwMNwyeYJWaxC%2B%2BOlGB44YU%3D)]
> - ✅`04a3a25320a7dc49dc6c8fda823fff1e5e3308e3 *build/us_pc/sm64.us.exe` [[logs](https://pipelinesghubeus8.actions.githubusercontent.com/p4R3lFxSm6lxRfpK94ViNn7tklFC2k5fO9TY2Z9EqhtckEjydu/_apis/pipelines/1/runs/12/signedlogcontent/2?urlExpires=2023-10-10T17%3A35%3A23.5835107Z&urlSigningMethod=HMACV1&urlSignature=qKkLfbJuQ5AVSHtq%2Fb5pjrksJyZ6ooyDpz7wZ3xNodw%3D)]
> - ❌`44b3a4c033d06bbce31e8d8f41be74dcc275b465 *build/us_pc/sm64.us.exe` [[logs](https://pipelinesghubeus8.actions.githubusercontent.com/p4R3lFxSm6lxRfpK94ViNn7tklFC2k5fO9TY2Z9EqhtckEjydu/_apis/pipelines/1/runs/13/signedlogcontent/2?urlExpires=2023-10-10T17%3A36%3A05.6630305Z&urlSigningMethod=HMACV1&urlSignature=Cgs6%2Bs42yQdsHOkFXDetL%2Bgrp87bI1eiSdchLJqgjnY%3D)]
> - ✅`0fbe7aa5ceae9758ea04355a04432aae160bf537 *build/us_pc/sm64.us.exe` [[logs](https://pipelinesghubeus8.actions.githubusercontent.com/p4R3lFxSm6lxRfpK94ViNn7tklFC2k5fO9TY2Z9EqhtckEjydu/_apis/pipelines/1/runs/11/signedlogcontent/2?urlExpires=2023-10-10T17%3A37%3A17.4274567Z&urlSigningMethod=HMACV1&urlSignature=sIb%2BytH9CY5sRHk%2B1BBIUE%2FHqZkDglO4xOJ54QYC8KQ%3D)]
> - ❌`3720a2fc1e37d38d4afb6799c07ce2b7fb530c4a *build/us_pc/sm64.us.exe` [[logs](https://pipelinesghubeus8.actions.githubusercontent.com/p4R3lFxSm6lxRfpK94ViNn7tklFC2k5fO9TY2Z9EqhtckEjydu/_apis/pipelines/1/runs/10/signedlogcontent/2?urlExpires=2023-10-10T17%3A37%3A55.6751136Z&urlSigningMethod=HMACV1&urlSignature=fVRMJ53zMwZPrwW%2FcgGXdMK10NYlvt4jCzrhhCjPDXg%3D)]
>
> Checksum matches for the ones produced by the workflow, the files uploaded to Artifacts, and those ones uploaded to Google Drive, so, it is not a ZIP corruption.

I have adopted the [Super Mario 64 port](https://github.com/Amitie10g/sm64-port) project to create Docker images with the tools and dependencies to successfully build usable executables for Linux (GCC 13) and Windows (MinGW-w64 GCC).

I attepted to build Windows executables using [mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc](https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc) (and its dependendencies) under the following Windows-based environments:

- **MSYS2** installed directly to a fresh Windows Server 2022 installation at Google Cloud using the GUI-based MSYS2 installer downloaded from the official website, then, install `mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc` and dependencies from the command line: **builds and runs** [[GDB output](https://gist.github.com/Amitie10g/d0c62c5895525b1b51af85248100464c#file-gdb-local-msys2)]
- **My [Docker container](https://hub.docker.com/r/amitie10g/sm64-port)** (basically the same as above, but MSYS2 installed using Chocolatey): **builds and runs**
- **GitHub Actions** using [this workflow](https://github.com/Amitie10g/sm64-port/actions/runs/6431259820/workflow) ([relevant logs](https://gist.github.com/Amitie10g/d0c62c5895525b1b51af85248100464c#build-fail-hexdump.log)) that uses the built-in MSYS2 environment: **build failed due missing `hexdump`**
- **GitHub Actions** using [this workflow](https://github.com/Amitie10g/sm64-port/actions/runs/6431266977/workflow)  that uses [`msys2/setup-msys2`](https://github.com/msys2/setup-msys2) to install a separated MSYS2 environment and dependencies in an attemp to solve the missing dependencies on the built-in MSYS2 env: **builds but fails to run** (no window, then process ended) [[Actions logs](https://gist.github.com/Amitie10g/d0c62c5895525b1b51af85248100464c#file-build-success-log)] [[GDB output](https://gist.github.com/Amitie10g/d0c62c5895525b1b51af85248100464c#file-gdb-github-actions)]

Is there I missed? Us there a way to install `hexdump` (util-linux) into the built-in MSYS2 environment?

I already finded further missing dependencies but the executable built in GitHub Actions platform is still unreproducible. Please note I'm not a developer, just a hobbist. Thanks in advance.